# Bedeutungsunterschied die Karre/der Karren

Tags: regional

Diese Begriffe stehen ursprünglich anscheinend für dasselbe und bezeichnen irgendwas wie einen Handwagen, mit dem Lasten transportiert werden. Im übertragenen Sinne können anscheinend auch beide Begriffe für ein abgewracktes, sich im schlechten Zustand befindliches Auto verwendet werden.

Laut Duden und anderen Wörterbüchern ist dieser Begriff im Süden des Sprachraums maskulin, im Norden feminin.

Meine Frage: Gibt es außer dieser Regionalspezialität irgendwelche Bedeutungsunterschiede? Ich suche auch nach Zusammensetzungen mit diesen Begriffen.

- Ich scheine wesentlich mehr Fundstellen für "die Schubkarre" als für "den Schubkarren" zu finden.
- Ich scheine wesentlich mehr Fundstellen für "die Schrottkarre" als für "den Schrottkarren" zu finden, die maskuline Form scheint mir sogar nur rein mundartlich zu sein.

Comment: Das ist nicht repräsentativ, aber *der Karren* ist für mich ein historisches Gefährt. Ein Auto würde ich nicht als *Karren* bezeichnen. Der Ausdruck *jmd. an den Karren fahren* funktioniert nicht mit *Karre*.

Comment: *Die Karre* → am ehesten *die Schubkarre*, einachsiges Gefährt. *Der Karren* → immer mehrachsig, aber *der Wagen, der Bollerwagen* wird bevorzugt. Als Name für abgewracktes Auto dann aber wieder *die Karre*. Seltsam. Ort: Braunschweiger Land, Harz.

Comment: Ich bin in Württemberg ganz klar mit "der Karren", "der Schubkarren", "der Schrottkarren" (Auto) usw. aufgewachsen. "Die Karre" zu sagen war und ist meinem Empfinden nach ein Merkmal weiter nördlich aufgewachsener Sprecher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anders als in Österreich existieren in Deutschland beide - eine maskuline und eine feminine - Varianten. Nur die regionale Verteilung ist verschieden; beide haben ansonsten eine identische Bedeutung. Selbst die gängigen Redewendungen existieren jeweils in beiden grammatikalischen Geschlechtern.

Das ist wenig verwunderlich, denn [noch zu Grimms Zeiten](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GK01929#XGK01929) galt anders als heute die femine Variante als eine Nebenform der ansonsten gebräuchlicheren maskulinen Form:

> **karre**, f. nebenform zum folg., in mitteld. gebieten geltend, wie thür., sächs., schles. (neben dem m.), ...

Allerdings ist mittlerweile die feminine Form in Deutschland häufiger geworden. Weshalb ist mir nicht bekannt.

Alle in den [Wörterbüchern zur femininen Form gelisteten Bedeutungen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Karre) kann ich als ein in Süddeutschland aufgewachsener auch für die maskuline Form und ihre Komposita nebst Redewendungen bestätigen. Ich kann keine Unterschiede finden. Das wird so [auch von meinem Wörterbuch bestätigt](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Karren) und ich will hier nicht alle auflisten (nur soviel: man kann schon auch jemand an die Karre fahren und ein alter (Schrott-)Karren ist durchaus ein altes Auto).

Spannend ist, dass es wohl schon im Latein zwei unterschiedliche Formen gab (*carrus* m. und *carrum* n.) und dass eine maskuline und eine feminine Form schon im Althochdeutsch bekannt war.

Answer (score 5):

Ich lebe im Süden, nämlich im Osten Österreichs, und auch hier ist *die Karre* weiblich. Ebenso ist hier aber auch *der Karren* bekannt, der männlich ist, aber einen anderen Begriff darstellt.

Ich beziehe mich hier auf den Gebrauch im Osten Österreichs (Wien, Niederösterreich, Burgenland und Steiermark), glaube aber, dass die beiden Wörter auch im Rest Österreichs, in Südtirol und Bayer, möglicherweise auch in der Schweiz und vielleicht sogar in nördlicheren Regionen des deutschen Sprachraums so verwendet werden:

- **die Karre**
  Das ist ein altes und schäbiges Auto. Ebenso die Schrottkarre. Dieses Wort ist hier zwar bereits Teil des alltäglichen Wortschatzes, wird aber noch nicht als richtig heimisch empfunden. Es klingt nicht österreichisch, sondern deutsch (hier ist mit *»deutsch«* nicht »deutschsprachig«, sondern »zu Deutschland gehörend« gemeint.)
- **der Karren**
  Dieses Wort ist in Österreich zwar bekannt, wird aber wenig verwendet. Es bezeichnet einen kleinen zweiachsigen hölzernen Wagen mit einer Deichsel, der üblicherweise von einem Menschen gezogen wird.
  Das gebräuchlichere Wort dafür ist in Österreich »Leiterwagerl« [ˈlaɪ̯tɐˌvaːɡɐl]. Das ist der Diminutiv von [Leiterwagen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leiterwagen).

Die Schubkarre ist zwar bekannt, wird in Österreich aber vornehmlich *»Scheibtruhe«* oder umgangssprachlich *»Scheibtruchn«* [ˈʃaɪ̯bˌtʀuːχn̩] genannt. Auch den aus dem Tschechischen entlehnten Begriff *»Tragatsch«* [ˈtʀaːɡaʧ] hört man in vielen Gegenden Ost-Österreichs.

Comment: Ich kenne *die Karre* auch noch als jugendsprachlich für "das Auto" ohne spezifische Wertung

Comment: Kenne ich so auch aus dem Raum Stuttgart

Answer (score 4):

Es handelt sich um verbreitete Mehrformigkeit, wobei jeweils eine schwache maskuline Form zu einer anderen gebildet wird, die oft feminin ist. Die Unterschiede dürften wohl meist regionaler Natur sein (in der Schweiz etwa heisst es nur *der Karren).*

Andere Beispiele (teils mit Ablaut oder Bedeutungsänderung):

- die Zacke/der Zacken
- die Socke/der Socken
- die Ecke/der Ecken/das Eck
- die Karre/der Karren
- die Fahne/der Fahnen
- die Balle/der Ballen/der Ball
- der Rest/der Resten
- der Tolgg/der Tolggen
- der Fetz/der Fetzen
- der Fleck/der Flecken
- die Zinke/der Zinken
- der Schirm/der Schermen
- der Stock/der Stecken
- der Lärm/der Lärmen
- die Spunte/der Spunten
- die Schlarpe/der Schlarpen
- die Scherbe/der Scherben